# can't find documentation on json.tool

Tags: python, json

I can find scattered articles online that use json.tool to produce pretty python, but no clear documentation on usage.  I checked [docs.python.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) but there is no formal documentation of json.tool.

I have a couple of workflows (written by other people) that use json.tool to validate json, but I have also seen posts that warn json.tool does not always produce valid json.  So I want to understand more about how json.tool works.

Can anyone recommend somewhere with clear, comprehensive documentation on json.tool?

Answer (score 23):

If you look through the formal documentation of the python JSON library you see that the invocation of `json.tool` should be `python -mjson.tool`. This indicates that the program in the file `tool.py` under the `json` directory of your python installation, or that it is in the file `__init__.py` in the `tool` directory under `json` in your python installation.

The file is actually the former of the two and its `main()` function is < 20 lines of code that can be easily analysed:

- if there are no arguments it functions as a pipe: JSON in and JSON out
- if there is one argument that is taken as JSON input file, output to stdout
- there are two arguments the first is JSON input file, the second the JSON output file

If you provide more parameters it will actually show the usage:

```
$ python -m json.tool a b c
/opt/python/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/json/tool.py [infile [outfile]]
```

That is for the 2.7 version of the tool. The 3.5.1 version has an extra parameter and there the parameters are shown if you use `-h`:

```
$ python -m json.tool -h

usage: python -m json.tool [-h] [--sort-keys] [infile] [outfile]

A simple command line interface for json module to validate and pretty-print
JSON objects.

positional arguments:
  infile       a JSON file to be validated or pretty-printed
  outfile      write the output of infile to outfile

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --sort-keys  sort the output of dictionaries alphabetically by key
```